# How do I get around aggregate function error?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following sql to calculate a % total:

```
SELECT tblTourns_atp.ID_Ti,
       Sum([FS_1]/(SELECT Sum(FSOF_1)
                   FROM stat_atp
                   WHERE stat_atp.ID_T = tblTourns_atp.ID_T)) AS S1_IP
FROM stat_atp
INNER JOIN tblTourns_atp ON stat_atp.ID_T = tblTourns_atp.ID_T
GROUP BY tblTourns_atp.ID_Ti
```

I'm getting the 'aggregate error' because it wants the `ID_T` fields either grouped or in an aggregate function. I've read loads of examples but none of them seem to apply when the offending field is the subject of 'WHERE'.

Tables and output as follows:

```
+----------+------+--------+--+---------------+-------+--+--------+--------+
| stat_atp |      |        |  | tblTourns_atp |       |  | Output |        |
+----------+------+--------+--+---------------+-------+--+--------+--------+
| ID_T     | FS_1 | FSOF_1 |  | ID_T          | ID_Ti |  | ID_Ti  | S1_IP  |
| 1        | 20   | 40     |  | 1             | 1     |  | 1      | 31.03% |
| 2        | 30   | 100    |  | 2             | 1     |  | 2      | 28.57% |
| 3        | 40   | 150    |  | 3             | 1     |  | 3      | 33.33% |
| 4        | 30   | 100    |  | 4             | 2     |  |        |        |
| 5        | 30   | 100    |  | 5             | 2     |  |        |        |
| 6        | 40   | 150    |  | 6             | 2     |  |        |        |
| 7        | 20   | 40     |  | 7             | 3     |  |        |        |
| 8        | 30   | 100    |  | 8             | 3     |  |        |        |
| 9        | 40   | 150    |  | 9             | 3     |  |        |        |
| 10       | 20   | 40     |  | 10            | 3     |  |        |        |
+----------+------+--------+--+---------------+-------+--+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I guess SUM inside SUM is throwing error. This is still a guess. Please post the data and expected result.

Comment: It works fine if I add ```tblTourns_atp.ID_T``` into the GROUP BY. Does that help? Data and output will take me 10-15 mins to put together and I figured there'd be a simple answer?

Comment: Since you are using tblTourns_atp.ID_T in select clause inside co-relatedsub-query, You have to use it in group by clause. If you can post the sample data & expected result, We can help you.

Comment: Updated withh some dummy data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `inner join` between the two tables, a separate subquery isn't required:

```
select t.id_ti, sum(s.fs_1)/sum(s.fsof_1) as pct 
from tbltourns_atp t inner join stat_atp s on t.id_t = s.id_t
group by t.id_ti
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Could you explain a little of the logic here in using the letters "s" and "t"?

Comment: You're most welcome - the letters `t` & `s` are merely table name aliases to save some typing, whilst also ensuring table qualifiers are used for each field.

Comment: Great, thanks! Could I be a little cheeky and ask; if there was a ```DATE``` field in table ```t``` how would you put a ```WHERE``` in that only sums the values for ```t.id_t``` where their ```DATE``` is less than or equal to the current record's ```DATE```?

Comment: Happy to help you answer that, but it would be clearer if presented as a separate question with the relevant sample data and expected result - it is difficult to interpret a description alone.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Added it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726102/where-do-i-put-a-where-statement